# Vue: Turning method into promise?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dropzone.js

I am using Dropzone to process images.  I am manually calling the image processing on a button click so inside a function called `submitAssets()`, I am doing this:

```
submitAssets: function() {
   this.$refs.dropzoneReference.processQueue();
   axios.get('/users')
}
```

Part of the processQueue call in dropzone hits my backend and saves the image url to the user object.
The problem is the axios call gets the info from the users object but the image has not been processed yet and saved to the DB.  Is there a way I can make that a Promise so that the axios call does not get called until processQueue is finished?

Comment: If it takes a callback you can convert it into a Promise with `new Promise()`.

Comment: does `processQueue` return a Promise already? or how is that defined?

Comment: use async await method

Comment: It may help to make use of [dropzone events](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#events) to handle your specific case. Maybe [queuecomplete](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-queuecomplete) if you want axios to fire when all uploads complete.

Answer (score 1):

If `processQueue` already returns a promise then you can just use `async/await`. Otherwise you will need to turn it into a promise for the following to work.

```
submitAssets: async function() {
   await this.$refs.dropzoneReference.processQueue();
   axios.get('/users')
}
```

And inside `processQueue` you can do something like:

```
const processQueue = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  ...make your changes
  resolve();
  });
}
```

Comment: `processQueue` is a method within the library of Vue Dropzone.  I just looked at the docs and it doesn't return a Promise.